# Getting the value of a constantly changing integer

Tags: java, android, integer, sensors

I'm working with android sensors, specifically TYPE_STEP_COUNTER. The value returned by TYPE_STEP_COUNTER is constantly increasing and there is not way of resetting it (as far as I know). What I need to do is get the number of steps taken from the point the user presses a button.

I would do:

```
int steps = overallTotal - totalWhenButtonPressed
```

How can I get the totalWhenButtonPressed value?

I can't do `totalWhenButtonPress = event.values[0]` because the value keeps changing.

Comment: can you explain why you can't do `totalWhenButtonPress = event.values[0]` because that's exactly what I would do. Primitive values are copied, your `total...` does not change when the other one changes, in case that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @zapl I can't do totalWhenButtonPress = event.values[0] because event.values[0] keeps continuously updating. So if I reference totalWhenButtonPress later the value will be the new value at event.values[0]

Comment: Exactly that's not the case. The moment that line executes, it copies the current value into `total..`. There is no connection between the two because `int` isn't a reference. And even if it was an object, you'd copy the reference to the current content of `values[0]`. You don't share the reference with `value[0]`. Everyone gets it's own reference to whatever it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value explains

Comment: No dice, my code:
'Sensor stepCtr = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        sm.registerListener(mSensorCounter, stepCtr, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);'

'private SensorEventListener mSensorCounter = new SensorEventListener() {
        
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            TextView txtStepVals = ...
            int ogSteps = Math.round(event.values[0]);
            double currSteps = event.values[0];
            txtStepVals.setText("CurrSteps = " + currSteps + "\nOgSteps = " + ogSteps + "\nSteps: " + (currSteps - ogSteps));
        }
    };'

Comment: I can't read that :) Please [edit] your question and format it nicely. Ps `int ogSteps` is that a local variable in a callback that is overwritten every time this method is called? https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html ("Local Variables Have No Memory")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using the TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR. Instead of trying to get the number at a point in time, I just updated the number as the action occurred. The following code is from the onSensorChanged method of the SensorEventListener

```
currSteps = currSteps + Math.round(event.values[0]);
        TextView txtSessionStepVals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSessionStepValues);
        txtSessionStepVals.setText("Steps this Session: " + currSteps);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work roughly like this

```
private int mLatestValue;
private int mButtonPressedValue;

void onCreate(..) {
    Sensor stepCtr = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    sm.registerListener(mSensorCounter, stepCtr, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    Button button = button.setOnClickListener(mButtonClick);
}

private OnClickListener mButtonClick = new OnClickListerner() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mButtonPressedValue = mLatestValue;
    }
}
private SensorEventListener mSensorCounter = new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        mLatestValue = Math.round(event.values[0]);
        txtStepVals.setText("CurrSteps = " + mLatestValue + "\nSteps: " + (mLatestValue - mButtonPressedValue));
    }
};
```

You need to store the current sensor outside of the `SensorEventListener` so you can store that value once the button is pressed. And then simply compare to the value you stored when the button was pressed.